# Split and reformat a String using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a string variable like:

```
string data= "#FirstName=Arvind #LastName= Chaudhary_009"
```

Using Regex in C# i Want the output like :

```
FirstName = Arvind;
LastName= Chaudhary009;
```

Comment: What have u tried so far?

Comment: is there some reason you have to use regex here? String.Split(new char[] {'  ', '#'}, StringSplitOptions Remove Empty) and then string.Replace("=", " = ") for the specific string example you give. Is there some variability in the input that makes it harder?

Comment: yes i want to do it in only c# because of some security purpose if you can do it than please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be more ways of doing this. Two of them would be

```
string data = "#FirstName=Arvind #LastName= Chaudhary_009";
data = data.Replace("_", "");
data = data.Replace("=", " = ");
string[] dt = data.Split(new char[] {'#'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(dt[0]); // Print your array here
```

**Regex**: Which you asked for

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"#");
string[] dt1 = regex.Split(data).Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(dt1[0]); // Print your array here
```

You can print array the way you want

### Edit

After Understanding the requirements from comments

```
string data = "#FirstName=Arvind #LastName= Chaudhary_009";
data = data.Replace("_", "");
string[] dt = data.Split(new char[] {'#'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Regex regex = new Regex(@"#");
string[] dt1 = regex.Split(data).Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray();

foreach(string d in dt)
{
    //this will print both the line
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}

foreach(string d in dt1)
{
    //this will print both the line
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

[image: Screenshot for showing the output]

Comment: I don't know the exact requirements here but, there are three things missing from your solution. Removing the _ from the last name, changing the second # into a ; and adding a ; at the end

Comment: Yeah the requirements are not clear. Whereas I assumed OP used `;` for telling that two splits of the string. and Yeah I completely ignored `_` in my solution. Lemme fix that.

Comment: string data = "#FirstName=Arvind  #LastName= Chaudhary_009"; and want FirstName=Arvind; and LastName= Chaudhary009

Comment: @Arvindchaudhary: does the code serve you what you were looking for?

Comment: If no space between the `=` than just ignore that line.

Comment: So u mean to say that your output will be only one string like `FirstName=Arvind LastName= Chaudhary009` is it ??

Comment: FirstName=Arvind  in first line and LastName= Chaudhary009 in second line ..............by using regex only

Answer (score 0):

There will be many solutions. I suggest you use [.NET Regex Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester) or a similar online tool to help develop a regex that works well.

A simple example regex that will give you some groups:

```
#FirstName\s*=\s*(.*)\s?#LastName\s*=\s*(.*)_(.*)
```

Run that and then format up the output based on groups 1, 2, 3.